# What options to use instead of the while loop

Tags: c#

The method below works but I"m not happy using a while loop.  Are there other options with examples I can use here?

This method is part of a com object that's called from external sources.  I have to do the same thing with about 30 other methods. All results coming back are immediate that take about 3 milliseconds.   The mentioned Queue is monitored by a task in another thread.  Once it run the execute, puts the results back in skyCommand then stores it in a ConcurrentDictionary.  The while loop is just waiting for it to appear or timeout.

```
   public void AxisStop(int axis)
    {
        var validAxis = ValidateAxis(axis);
        var id = Convert.ToInt32($"10{RandomNumber()}");
        var skyAxisStop = new SkyAxisStop {Id = id};
        skyAxisStop.AxisStop(validAxis);
        TelescopeHardware.SkyRequestQueue.Enqueue(skyAxisStop);
        var timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        while (timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < ReplyTimer && !TelescopeHardware.SkyResultDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            if (!TelescopeHardware.SkyResultDictionary.TryRemove(id, out var skyCommand)) continue;
            if (skyCommand.Successful) 
            {
                // deal with the results here...
            }
            else
            {
                throw skyCommand.Exception;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds >= ReplyTimer) throw new Exception("Timeout waiting on reply");
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: I mean, you could use a `for` loop if you wanted to... what's wrong with `while`?

Comment: It sounds like you've implemented something like a publish-subscribe pattern so there's nothing wrong with a `while` - provided it's in it's own thread (so it isn't blocking or hogging any main processing or rendering threads).

Comment: Should you have a delay somewhere? Something seems wrong in the while logic.

Comment: Btw Your if (timer >= elapsed) statement after the while loop is unnecessary

Comment: Can you change the COM client to use events so you don't have to block?

Comment: The while is blocking the main UI thread for a few milliseconds. Not sure I can get around this especially for methods that need to return something to the client. If I use a task to call my queue and get the result it still has to wait.  I do want to make sure all commands are successfully executed and don't cause a timeout and I don't have any control over the com clients calling this.  It's meant to be open for all scripting languages.